# Unable to get a expected output using hive aggregate function

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I have a created a table (**movies**) in Hive as below(**id,name,year,rating,views**)

`1,The Nightmare Before Christmas,1993,3.9,4568
2,The Mummy,1932,3.5,4388
3,Orphans of the Storm,1921,3.2,9062
4,The Object of Beauty,1991,2.8,6150
5,Night Tide,1963,2.8,5126
6,One Magic Christmas,1985,3.8,5333
7,Muriel's Wedding,1994,3.5,6323
8,Mother's Boys,1994,3.4,5733
9,Nosferatu: Original Version,1929,3.5,5651
10,Nick of Time,1995,3.4,5333`

**I want to write a hive query to get the name of the movie with highest views.**

> select name,max(views) from movies;

but it gives me an error
`FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key name`

but doing a group by with **name** gives me the complete list (which is expected).
What changes should I make to my query?

Comment: you need to have a group by clause

Comment: group by name gives me all the movie names and their views, but not the movie with max views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little bit of digging, I found out that the answer is not so straightforward as we do in SQL. Below query gives the expected result.

`select a.name,a.views from movies a left semi join(select max(views) views from movies)b on (a.views=b.views);`

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that there is a simpler way to do this.

```
select name 
from(
    select max(views) as views
        , name
        , row_number() over (order by max(views) desc) as row_num 
    from movies  
    group by name
) m
where row_num = 1
```

Comment: It gives the below error


`FAILED: Parse Error: line 5:25 mismatched input '(' expecting FROM near 'over' in from clause`